# Modify custom portlet jsp

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet

I am new to Liefray. I want to change custom portlet jsps in Liferay. I don't have war files of these portlets, only files from webapps folder. How can I do this? I can't find any information regarding this simple question.

Comment: Well, Liferay has quite decent [documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/customizing-liferay-portal), have you read it?

Comment: Yes. There is no information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't find any information on this topic because it's considered very bad practice to modify anything on this stage. While it's possible to change JSPs (and package a WAR file from the webapps directory), you'll create a maintenance mess. And as soon as you want to change any Java code, you probably don't have that source code as well.

Do yourself a favor and reconstruct a proper development environment, put the portlets under source control and deploy them properly.

From your use of "webapps" I'm assuming you're on tomcat. Unless tomcat is configured to ignore changed JSPs, you can (technically) just go in and change that JSP. If you'd do this in any system that I maintain, you'd immediately loose any access to server systems for doing so. However that system is maintained: Go through the way that the plugin has been installed in the first place. Go to the vendor and ask them for the source version.

Or, if there is no source code, get hold of the original WAR file and at least use the well documented technique of creating a [plugin to extend a plugin](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-plugins-to-extend-plugins).

Comment: Thank you. Then I'll stop wasting time on this idea.